# Are trading skills important for caravans

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

Are the trading skills of the companion in charge of a caravan relevant for its earnings or can I just assign anyone? And are there any other skills relevant for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no they are not, your trading skill does impact it with perks but other than this it doesn't matter CURRENTLY the skills of who is running the caravan.

I do however imagine this will change.